# Is it actually possible to have a background service always runing even after reboot?

Tags: java, android, service

I'm looking to make an app without UI, which runs in the background (service?).
Its only function will be to detect the IP change, make an HTTP request, and send a notification with the result of the request.

I know how to do all of this more or less well, even I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly, but I can't resolve the following point:
When rebooting, this "service" should be reactivated without action on the part of the user.

Could you please tell me if this is possible (I find so many examples that no longer work today) and if so, what are the "bricks" that I must put in place?

**EDIT:**

Since clearly what I want is not possible, and I understand why, I will re-specify what I would like, to find out what you could offer me.

Basically, I would like my application to be restarted after reboot (if it was started before the reboot).
However, I can clearly see it in the background, but it is not executed.
The BroadcastReceiver's onReceive is activated, but I don't know what I can do with it since what I want to execute needs to be linked to an activity.

my code is more or less:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                pokeServer(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
}


private void pokeServer(Activity activity) {
    final String URL = "https://***";
    final String ident = "ident";
    final String pwd = "passwd";
    final String NOTOK = "injoignable";
    new BackgroundTask(activity) {
    private String result;

    @Override
    public void doInBackground() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        final String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((ident + ":" + pwd).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URL).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response != 200) {
                this.result = null;
                return;
            }

            inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                this.result = null;
                return;
            }

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
                buffer.append("\n");
            }
            this.result = new String(buffer);
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.result = null;
            return;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) conn.disconnect();
            if (inputStream != null)
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute() {
        if (this.result == null) this.result = NOTOK;
        Toast vwToast = Toast.makeText(activity, this.result.trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        vwToast.show();
        NotificationScheduler.notification(activity, this.result);
        activity.finishAffinity();
    }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: "I'm looking to make an app without UI" -- how do you anticipate that the app will ever run? What specifically will move it out of the initial "stopped state"?

Comment: @CommonsWare As told after, my app is started, not closed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a service always running in the background at all.  Background services are killed after 2 minutes.  Always.  Foreground services last longer, but can still be killed at any time.

However, that doesn't mean you can't achieve what you actually need.  There's a variety of ways to have work done asynchronously.  But "keep a service around to do it" isn't one of those ways.  TO help further, we'd need to know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I deduce from your answer and that of @CommonsWare that what I would have liked to do is not possible, and I perfectly understand why.
Basically, what I would have simply wanted is for my application to be restarted after reboot (if it was started before the reboot), and that would be enough for me. However, I can clearly see it in the background, but it is not executed. Maybe I just need to handle a state differently.
I will search in this direction.

Comment: "_Background services are killed after 2 minutes. Always_" – Is this documented? Because [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) seems to contradict that statement. But I'm definitely not an Android expert.

Comment: Never mind. [This](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) seems to answer my question.

Comment: @Slaw The two is experimentally determined (and future builds could tweak it, don't depend on getting a certain amount).  But yes, the background limitations covers the behavior

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for the BOOT_COMPLETED action. This broadcast is sent when the device finishes booting. In this BroadcastReceiver, you'll start your background service.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Start your background service here
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourBackgroundService.class);
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Declare Permissions: In your AndroidManifest.xml, you'll need to declare permissions for receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and for running a background service:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

Create Your Background Service: Create a background service that will perform your desired tasks, such as detecting IP changes and making HTTP requests. Extend the Service class and implement the necessary logic in the onStartCommand method.

```
public class YourBackgroundService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Perform your background tasks here
        
        // Return START_STICKY to ensure the service is restarted if it's killed
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Register BroadcastReceiver: Register your BootReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Start Service on App Launch: To start your service when the app is launched, you can do this in your app's main activity or a launcher activity:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, YourBackgroundService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but, as Gabe Sechan told, it can't work because "Background services are killed after 2 minutes. Always. Foreground services last longer, but can still be killed at any time"